# jquery not posting array data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

ive tried 10  different solutions to this issue on stackoverflow and none of them work, heres the issue, i need to post a array via ajax to a url
simple right?

the array comes from post values like this $_post[xxx] which i store in a var.

i mocked up a js function, that has the same error, instead of passing the array i just included as a  var in the function, problem is the data is not gettin posted to the url.
pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/8ivWqJ8g

```
function generateImage() {
 var Imagedata = [];

Imagedata['id'] = 1;
Imagedata['type'] = 'some type';


        var url = '';
         $.ajax({
            url: url,
              processData: false,
             dataType: 'JSON',
              data:  JSON.stringify(Imagedata) ,

             method:'POST',
              async: false
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Named properties of arrays do not get serialised when you convert the data to JSON.

Arrays are supposed to hold an ordered set of values, not an arbitrary set of name:value pairs.

Use a plain object (`{}`) not an array.

---

Asides:

Don't use `processData: false` unless you are passing something that isn't a string or an object to `data` (e.g. a `FormData` object). Since you are passing a string, it is harmless, but pointless. If you were passing an object (which you probably should be, see below), it would break things.

Don't use `async: false`. It is deprecated, and harms the user experience (since it locks up the JS thread until the response arrives).

If you want to populate PHP's `$_POST` then don't format your data as JSON. Pass the object directly to `data:` without using `JSON.stringify`.

If you do want to make a JSON formatted request, then don't forget to set the `contentType`.

---

```
function generateImage() {
  var Imagedata = {
    id: 1,
    type: "some type"
  };

  var url = '';

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: Imagedata,
    method: 'POST'
  });

  // or …

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(Imagedata),
    method: 'POST'
  });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

data should be an Object like this:

```
     $.ajax({
        url: 'http://...',
         dataType: 'JSON',
          data:  {id: 1, type: 'some type'} ,

         method:'POST',
          async: false
        });
```

Comment: That won't work. The POSTed data will be `[object Object]` since you set `processData: false`.